# Integration-Manager Git Workflow using Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: eclipse, git, hudson, jenkins, junit4

I'm trying to  implement a modified Integration-Manager workflow similar to what's described in [ProGit](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html).

[image: Diagram of the Integration-Manager workflow]

Instead of an `integration manager` performing the merges, I want developers to merge locally before publishing their code, and I want a `Quality Gateway` that enforces our continuous integration standards, such as a minimum level of code coverage and 100% tests passing, before allowing code to enter the blessed repository to be checked out by other developers. The idea is that the code in the blessed repository always meets the minimum standard we define and always builds.

I want Jenkins to perform the role of the quality gateway, only pushing code to the blessed repository when builds succeed.

So far, I have set up the system so that there are the following public repos: the blessed repository, a repository on the build server for Jenkins, which is a bare repo accessed through gitosis, and of course developer's own repositories.

I have developers pulling from the blessed repo and pushing to the integration repo. Now I'm trying to get Jenkins to push successful builds from the integration repo to the blessed repo.

So far, the only option I've seen that seems similar to what I'm trying to achieve is the "`Push Only If Build Succeeds`" option in the Git Publisher settings of the Post Build Actions in Jenkins' project configuration. However, that options doesn't allow you to specify the push url or remote to push to.

As I understand it, the Git Publisher settings would push the repo Jenkins' clones into its workspace back into Jenkins' public repo, but I want to push to a different remote, the blessed repository.

**Does anyone have any suggestions how I can get Jenkins to push to the blessed repo?**

**EDIT 0**:
I tried putting a Post Step to execute the push command to my blessed repository. This appears to work, in that there are no errors. However no changes are being pushed and the logs show that git thinks everything is up to date:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL 
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 7 seconds 
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 18 16:10:50 UTC 2011 
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/45M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
channel stopped 
[My Project] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5604254372179801803.sh + git push git@example.com:my-project.git --all
Everything up-to-date
```

I don't know why git thinks there's nothing to push, because there definitely is.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the Jenkins "Push Only If Build Succeeds" action, with a post-commit or post-receive hook on the integration repository, to push to the blessed repository whenever Jenkins pushes after a successful build?

Comment: +1, although it's worth noting that this will only push the branch that triggered the change. If you've pushed tags or changes to more than 1 branch, they won't get pushed (We're currently using 1 project per repo, rather than setting up 1 project per branch, as we create lots of branches that we want to push through continuous integration)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) to your workflow.  Changes are pushed to Gerrit and then your CI runs a build and reports on your tests.  It can be set up so that other approvals (like authorized code reviews) are needed before it is merged into your blessed repo.  [EGit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit) uses it in their development, http://egit.eclipse.org/r/ .  There are other discussions of this workflow as well, like, [alblue](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/02/gerrit-git-review-with-jenkins-ci.html)'s blog.

Comment: Looks interesting, but the only thing it adds that our current process doesn't have is a formalised review process. Our projects are mavenised, so if they pass the build we know they pass the tests and other requirements we've defined. It doesn't seem to add enough (to our process) to justify having another tool complicate our environment. I'll keep in mind as our needs change though, thanks!

Comment: I understand the need to limit complexity :-)  I just mean it adds both the review and it reports the CI/Test pass results on each change before it gets committed to your blessed repo.